# Cassandra: @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = " ") can not set column name over attribute of entity's name

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, cassandra

Here I declare an entity like this. I use Cassandra

```
@Table(value = "messages_by_id")
public class Email {
    @Id
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id",ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID timeUUID;
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private String from;
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.LIST, typeArguments = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private List<String> to;
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private String subject;
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private String body;
```

But then when created and shown in database it did not set name of Key column as "id" as set in  @PrimaryKeyColumn but follow the attribute name is "timeUUID"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ52V.png)
If you want more info to resolve, don't hesitate to ask me.

Just give me away to set the column name by using annotation attribute. Is this related to JPA or Hibernate ?

Comment: PrimaryKeyColumn isn't part of the JPA specification, so you are mixing JPA with other mapping mechanisms that JPA isn't supposed to know about. ID here isn't even JPA - so this is not covered by JPA at all. In this case, you have confused the two similar Spring annotations - PrimaryKeyColumn is used when you have a composite pk to identify the many columns involved, while ID or  PrimaryKey are used on the single properties. If you turn on logging, hopefully Spring would tell you it has a problem with the mappings and is ignoring the  PrimaryKeyColumn one, but Spring usually just continues

Answer (score 1):

Chris' comment is correct.  In your case, I would use the `@PrimaryKey` annotation, instead:

```
@Table("messages_by_id")
public class Email {
    @PrimaryKey("id")
    private UUID timeUUID;
```

For more info, I have an entity class called [UserEntity.java](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/blob/3d19ba0b79ea9e2193dedf1eb6af8edeff7e6ce1/backend/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorials/service/user/UserEntity.java) which uses this example.  It's also part of a much larger project ([DataStax's E-Commerce Workshop](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app)) which contains ways to properly annotate primary keys in Cassandra.